# Supress message "Java was started but returned exit code"

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I would like to return a value from an Equinox application that will be evaluated by the parent application that started it. To achieve this I return the value from the `IApplication.start()` method. This works as expected, but I always get a message box

> Java was started but returned exit code ....

Is there a way to suppress this message?

Or is there another API to set the return value of the application?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but here it goes:  pass `--launcher.suppressErrors` as an argument to your executable.

I found this info on [this page](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-09/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html), which lists many other possible arguments.